# Sanskrit(Custom) language in iOS app localization

Tags: ios, localization, localizable.strings

I have localized my iPhone app to different languages successfully. I localize the Localizable.string to different languages and app is working fine. However I am not able to find out the `Sanskrit` language support in Xcode. How can I add the Sanskrit language support in my app?

[image]

Answer (score -1):

I display all the iOS supporting languages with the codes below, and found the language `Tibetan (India)` maybe the same language as `Sanskrit`, it's localeIdentifier name is `bo_IN`.

So you can add the language `Tibetan (India)` (བོད་སྐད་ (རྒྱ་གར་) - bo_IN) in Other.

(I need at least 10 reputation to post images ...Orz)

[Image Link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fOxkL.png)

```
NSArray *allLanguage = [NSLocale availableLocaleIdentifiers];
NSLocale *locale = [[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"bo_IN"];
NSLog(@"AllLanguage:");
[allLanguage enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(id _Nonnull obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL * _Nonnull stop) {
    NSString *readableString = [locale localizedStringForLocaleIdentifier:obj];
    printf("%s - %s \n", [readableString UTF8String], [obj UTF8String]);
}];
```